# Как указать классу RecyclerView.Adapter начальное состояние?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

Активити содержит RecyclerView. Данные в ArrayList. ArrayList содержит несколько сотен элементов. RecyclerView.Adapter подключает ArrayList к RecyclerView. При запуске активити на экране я вижу вертикальный список элементов из ArrayList. Самым верхним элементом экрана является самый первый элемент массива. Мне нужно добиться, чтобы при открытии активити RecyclerView сразу выводил самым верхним не первый элемент массива, а другой(например 50-й). Подскажите, как этого можно добиться?

Comment: при вызове onBindViewHolder есть позиция в RV можете подставить какую-угодно из списка

Comment: @Style-7 проще уже измененный список подавать в адаптер. зачем в нем что то делать

Comment: формируйте свой список в любом порядке. и просто отображайте его. при чем тут адаптер?

Comment: @Cypher, дело в том, что в RV список должен выводится в алфавитном порядке.   Пользователь должен попасть на определённый элемент (например элемент на букву Д), но он должен понимать, что выше есть ещё элементы на А, Б, В, Г.  И он может на них перейти пролистав RV вниз. Менять порядок элементов нельзя

Comment: @Style-7, к сожалению я не понял ваш совет. Как использовать int position для того, чтобы в RV (при выводе его на экран) верхним элементом был элемент с этим номером?

Comment: @gibsonff попробуйте использовать RecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(postion); чтобы при открытии происходил скролл к определенной позиции

Comment: index = list.size() - position - 1; теперь по этому индексу берите из списка, все отобразится в обратном порядке

Comment: @Cypher, так мне не нужно скролиться, мне нужно сразу попасть на нужный элемент. Т.е. открывается экран и RV уже установлен на нужном элементе.

Comment: @gibsonff используйте scrollToPosition(position) и сразу будет установлен на нужном элементе без скролла

Comment: @Cypher scrollToPosition(position) работает так как мне нужно. Спасибо. Может быть подскажете как решить точно такую же проблему с ViewPager2. В активити ViewPager2, адаптер точно такой же RecyclerView.Adapter. Для перепрыгивания на нужную страницу использую ViewPager2.setCurrentItem(position). Та же самая проблема: страницы визуально мелькают, перед тем как попасть на нужную. Чем заменить метод scrollToPosition(position)? Нужно сразу попасть на нужную страницу без пролистывания.

Comment: @gibsonff просто добавьте второй параметр viewPager.setCurrentItem(position, false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `RecyclerView.scrollToPosition()`.
Например у нас есть 10 элементов и нам надо открывать на пятом:

[image: ezgif-com-gif-maker-1.gif]

`Activity`:

```
class ScrollToPosActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scroll_to_pos)

    recycler_view.adapter = ScrollToPosAdapter(getDates())
    recycler_view.scrollToPosition(5)
}

private fun getDates() = listOf("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10")
}
```

`Adapter`:

```
class ScrollToPosAdapter(private val dates: List<String>) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<ScrollToPosAdapter.ScrollToPosViewHolder>() {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) = ScrollToPosViewHolder(
    LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_main, parent, false)
)

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ScrollToPosViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.text.text = dates[position]
}

override fun getItemCount() = dates.size

class ScrollToPosViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    val text: TextView = view.title
}
}
```